# Transparent outline on macOS isn't transparent?

Tags: html, css, macos, webkit

I'm wondering what's peculiar about the behavior out `outline-color` on macOS compared with Windows and Linux that makes a `transparent` outline grayish? Is it an accessibility thing?

I can hide it by setting `outline-width: 0`, but I'd like to understand why this is necessary. This is happening in WebKit-based browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=outline) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-color), outline-color is a well supported property in Safari.

Are you sure there aren't any outline-color property written later in the stylesheet?

By the way, to remove it completely you can use

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: Good find! Unfortunately the issue is present in a Chromium-based browser. I want to avoid `outline: none` for accessibility reasons, although I'm not really sure that setting it to transparent is any better at all for accessibility.

Comment: If you are worried about accessibility, you can just add other styles when the elements get focused. Outline helps when someone is browsing the site using "tab key". Check this cool article on [CSS outlines](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/)